# Angular Multiple Projects in one main application

Tags: angular

This is what I need for a project:

You have a main program that has x subapplications.

The main program is supposed to be called by the URL ( /example1/....  -> subprogram 1, /example2/....   -> load subprogram 2 | all with a own router-outlet)

However, the subroutines should be independent and loaded with their own app.component.html with their own router-outlet.

I found a project:

https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

there almost everything works as I imagined but the components of the subapps are loaded directly into the main router-outlet (the app.component.html of the respective subapps is not used). Now the question is whether it is possible to load the app.component.html of the apps instead of the actual component.

Current Tree Structure

```
D:.
|   .editorconfig
|   .gitignore
|   .travis.yml
|   angular.json
|   dir
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   tsconfig.json
|   tslint.json
|   
+---e2e
|   |   protractor.conf.js
|   |   tsconfig.e2e.json
|   |   
|   \---src
|           app.e2e-spec.ts
|           app.po.ts
|              
+---projects
|   +---sub-app1
|   |   |   browserslist
|   |   |   karma.conf.js
|   |   |   tsconfig.app.json
|   |   |   tsconfig.spec.json
|   |   |   tslint.json
|   |   |   
|   |   \---src
|   |       |   favicon.ico
|   |       |   index.html
|   |       |   main.ts
|   |       |   polyfills.ts
|   |       |   styles.css
|   |       |   test.ts
|   |       |   
|   |       +---app
|   |       |   |   app-routing.module.ts
|   |       |   |   app.component.css
|   |       |   |   app.component.html
|   |       |   |   app.component.spec.ts
|   |       |   |   app.component.ts
|   |       |   |   app.module.ts
|   |       |   |   
|   |       |   +---nav
|   |       |   |       nav.component.css
|   |       |   |       nav.component.html
|   |       |   |       nav.component.spec.ts
|   |       |   |       nav.component.ts
|   |       |   |       
|   |       |   +---view1
|   |       |   |       view1.component.css
|   |       |   |       view1.component.html
|   |       |   |       view1.component.spec.ts
|   |       |   |       view1.component.ts
|   |       |   |       
|   |       |   \---view2
|   |       |           view2.component.css
|   |       |           view2.component.html
|   |       |           view2.component.spec.ts
|   |       |           view2.component.ts
|   |       |           
|   |       +---assets
|   |       |       .gitkeep
|   |       |       
|   |       \---environments
|   |               environment.prod.ts
|   |               environment.ts
|   |               
|   \---sub-app2
|       |   browserslist
|       |   karma.conf.js
|       |   tsconfig.app.json
|       |   tsconfig.spec.json
|       |   tslint.json
|       |   
|       \---src
|           |   favicon.ico
|           |   index.html
|           |   main.ts
|           |   polyfills.ts
|           |   styles.css
|           |   test.ts
|           |   
|           +---app
|           |   |   app-routing.module.ts
|           |   |   app.component.css
|           |   |   app.component.html
|           |   |   app.component.spec.ts
|           |   |   app.component.ts
|           |   |   app.module.ts
|           |   |   
|           |   +---nav
|           |   |       nav.component.css
|           |   |       nav.component.html
|           |   |       nav.component.spec.ts
|           |   |       nav.component.ts
|           |   |       
|           |   +---view1
|           |   |       view1.component.css
|           |   |       view1.component.html
|           |   |       view1.component.spec.ts
|           |   |       view1.component.ts
|           |   |       
|           |   \---view2
|           |           view2.component.css
|           |           view2.component.html
|           |           view2.component.spec.ts
|           |           view2.component.ts
|           |           
|           +---assets
|           |       .gitkeep
|           |       
|           \---environments
|                   environment.prod.ts
|                   environment.ts
|                   
\---src
    |   browserslist
    |   favicon.ico
    |   index.html
    |   karma.conf.js
    |   main.ts
    |   polyfills.ts
    |   styles.scss
    |   test.ts
    |   tsconfig.app.json
    |   tsconfig.spec.json
    |   tslint.json
    |   
    +---app
    |   |   app-routing.module.ts
    |   |   app.component.html
    |   |   app.component.scss
    |   |   app.component.spec.ts
    |   |   app.component.ts
    |   |   app.module.ts
    |   |   
    |   \---nav
    |           nav.component.html
    |           nav.component.scss
    |           nav.component.spec.ts
    |           nav.component.ts
    |           
    +---assets
    |       .gitkeep
    |       
    \---environments
            environment.prod.ts
            environment.ts
```

Comment: Hello!, have you found a solution?